# Synchronus loading of bundles like RequireJS with webpack bundle-loader

Tags: webpack

I am trying to migrate my big single page application from Require.js to webpack and there is some troubles with code splitting. My application has structure:

```
js --|
|    |-- entry.js
|    |-- components --|
|                     |-- component_1.js
|                     |-- component_2.js
|                     ... // many components 
|                     |-- component_n.js
|    |-- pages --|
|                |-- page_1.js
|                |-- page_2.js
|                ... // many pages
|                |-- page_n.js
|    |-- routers --|
|                  |-- router.js
```

So I want to create a separate bundle for every page. I'm using bundle-loader in my router.js to do this:

```
require('bundle!pages/' + pageName)(function (result) {
      //... to do something in callback when the page is loaded
});
```

It's OK. Also every page has define section with some components (not all) that it needs. For example:

```
define([
    'components/component_1',
    'components/component_7',
    'components/component_29'
], function (c1, c2, c3) { 
   // ... to do something with OBJECTS c1, c2, c3.
});
```

Webpack puts code of these components on bundle with page. But there are many pages which use same components and components may be big, so I have duplicated code. ( DedupePlugin don't work with bundle-loader ). Also I don't want to create common big bundle with all components. I want to have isolated components and load each of them synchronously with page.
RequireJS solved this problem. First it loaded every component.js file (if it was not loaded before) and after loaded page.js. Of course, I can use bundle-loader for components in webpack:

```
define([
    'bundle!components/component_1',
    'bundle!components/component_7',
    'bundle!components/component_29'
], function (c1, c2, c3) { 
   // ??? what to do with CALLBACKS c1, c2, c3 ?
});
```

Then components are loading asynchronously with page, i.e. after the page is loaded. And c1, c2, c3 are callbacks, but i need to use them as objects. Or I need to rework my big app totally. It's so hard and long.
I tried to write custom loader based on bundle-loader. It's [here](https://github.com/yelodia/bundle-amd-loader). How to use it with callback:

```
require('bundle-amd!pages/' + pageName)(function (result) {
      //... to do something in callback when the page is loaded
});
```

How to use it in define section (with define parameter):

```
define([
    'bundle-amd?define!components/component_1',
    'bundle-amd?define!components/component_7'
], function (c1, c2) { 
   // ... to do something with OBJECTS c1, c2
});
```

My code is bad, because I am not nodejs developer, it's my first experience. But loader works and there are no duplicated code in bundles. I appeal to the experienced developer. Please, if you have the opportunity, create this loader (or plugin) for mass use. I think, I'm not the only one who needs the ability to synchronus loading of bundles. Hope you help me. Thanks!

Comment: Synchronous loading through AJAX is being taken out of the standard and won't work at some point not too long into the future. Why do you need the loading to be synchronous anyway? Can it not be accomplished asynchronously?

Comment: Why it won't work? It always works in Require.js. If component has define section, require.js first loads all scripts from section and after execute function. I want to have this ability with webpack. It cannot be accomplished asynchronously because there are several callbacks in define section, and I need to execute function with objects ( or when all callbacks will be resolved. )

Comment: If you need to load scripts synchronously then put them in `<script></script>`. Then the browser will load them synchronously. Otherwise you have to download the script through AJAX and you'll be limited to the deprecated synchronous loading method which is being phased out. Your best bet if you want your application to work properly with these technologies is to convert your application to load asynchronously. I don't see why that should be too hard, as long as you load your scripts in the proper order and context.